# ¿Cómo solucionar un error de EOFError: EOF when reading a line en Phyton?

Tags: funciones, input, float, python-3.9

¿Me podrían ayudar a identificar algún error de línea en Spyder? he estado intentando sacar el perímetro de un triángulo, pero al momento de correr los resultados me sale:

```
"Error on line 1:
    s1= float(input("Digite longitud de uno de los lados del triángulo"))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line" 

1. s1= float(input("Digite Longitud de uno de los lados del triángulo"))
2. s2= float(input("Digite Longitud de uno de los lados del triángulo"))
3. s3= float(input("Digite Longitud de uno de los lados del triángulo"))
4.   s= (s1+s2+s3)/2
5.   print (“El subperímetro es”+srt(s))
```

He tratado de hacer estos ejercicios previamente, pero no encuentro error en el proceso.